# Launching DEBUG from F11 opens "/WEB-INF/....../././Someclass.Java"?

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

Everytime I try to debug an MVC project, and press <kbd>F11</kbd> to do so, it launches the URL to /WEB-INF/.../../../SomeClass .jsp or .java. Why can't it just open the default
http:// localhost :8080/myproject/ - URL ?

Comment: Can you post a URL to a sample project that causes this? And is it deployed to tc server, running as a standalone app, or deployed to a different web server?

Comment: @MartinLippert: It's actually any project I create. Maybe this is intentional.

I should add, this only occurs as long as I have a .JSP-file or .JAVA-file open in the editor window. If I close all documents and then press F11 it opens the current project as it should, ie http://localhost:8080/MyMvcTestProject...

Comment: this sounds like a bug. Can you file a more detailed report at: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS